# Docker Toolbox Error: Looks like something went wrong in step 'Setting env'

Tags: docker, installation, windows-7, docker-toolbox

I had Docker Toolbox installed on my Windows 7 PC and I wanted to upgrade my Docker installation to the most recent version. To do that, I decided to delete Docker Toolbox from my system and reinstall it. I uninstalled Docker Toolbox, uninstalled VirtualBox, and removed all instances of both in my files (such as files in AppData). After reinstalling Docker Toolbox and launching the Quickstart Terminal, I ran into the following error:

```
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...    
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this vi
rtual machine, run: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe env defau
lt
Looks like something went wrong in step 'Setting env'... Press any key to contin
ue...
```

So it seems like it failed when "setting env". I'm not sure what that means in this context and I wish there was a way to check some extended logs to get more detail. I tried following the Docker documentation pointing the location of daemon logs in AppData, however, I could not find anything relevant. Something I did find was a file called "no-error-report", though it was empty.

I tried uninstalling everything again and reinstalling with the attribute NDIS5 network type checked, I've ran the Quickstart Terminal as admin, and I still ran into the same exact error.

Any suggestions on how I may approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this same issue. 
I fixed this by doing the below procedures.

I changed the below lines in start.sh

```
STEP="Setting env"
eval "$("${DOCKER_MACHINE}" env --shell=bash --no-proxy "${VM}" | sed -e "s/export/SETX/g" | sed -e "s/=/ /g")" &> /dev/null #for persistent Environment Variables, available in next sessions
eval "$("${DOCKER_MACHINE}" env --shell=bash --no-proxy "${VM}")" #for transient Environment Variables, available in current session
```

Changed --no-proxy to --http_proxy since I am using http proxy